# warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

Could someone help me to understand why the code-line below return:

> warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

```
qFileTxtName = @"110327";
aString = [@"xxxx_" stringByAppendingString:qFileTxtName];
```

What i am trying to get as an output is:

> xxxx_110327

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
NSString *aString = @"xxxx_";
aString = [aString stringByAppendingString:qFileTextName];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `qFileTxtName` and `aString` are both defined as `NSString*`, then the code you've provided does not produce any warning.

```
NSString *qFileTxtName = @"110327";
NSString *aString = [@"xxxx_" stringByAppendingString:qFileTxtName];
// no warnings
```

I think you meant to write `-stringByAppendingFormat:`, which *would* produce a warning:

```
NSString *qFileTxtName = @"110327";
NSString *aString = [@"xxxx_" stringByAppendingFormat:qFileTxtName]; 
// warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

If you really wanted to use `-stringByAppendingFormat:`, you'd need to do something like this:

```
NSString *aString = [@"xxxx_" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", qFileTxtName];
```

The following logging calls show another operation that would result in that warning from the compiler, and the better (more secure) way to code it:

```
NSLog(aString); // warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

NSLog(@"%@", aString); // the more secure way to do it
```

Comment: If really in need to use "stringByAppendingFormat", 
NSString *aString = [@"xxxx_" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", qFileTxtName];  does the job ..! 
Thanks @NSGod.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not declared them elsewhere, try

```
NSString *qFileTxtName = @"110327";
NSString *aString = [@"xxxx_" stringByAppendingString:qFileTxtName];
```

Answer (score 0):

This the problem of formater. In newer version of ios sdk there is a new method introdue for this. So use stringWithString instead of stringWithFormat. As below.

```
 NSMutableArray * array_mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"tekst"];
        NSString *s1;
        s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]]; //(Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
        s1 = [NSString stringWithString:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]]; //no problem
```